# Rename [tag:sexual misconduct] -> [tag:sexual conduct]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retagging

I propose to rename the tag [sexual-misconduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-misconduct) to [sexual-conduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-conduct), with a redirect. This is because "misconduct" already implies a judgment that the behavior is inappropriate, and in some questions this is a premature conclusion; for instance, the question may be *Is doing X OK?".

This proposal follows from an exchange with user @ff524 in the comments
to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/sex-worker-student-offering-her-legal-services). TL;DR:

- The question was initially tagged [sexual-misconduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-misconduct)
- I initially retagged the question [sexual-misconduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-misconduct) -> [sexual-sphere](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-sphere), out of this concern.
- She reverted the change arguing that [sexual-sphere](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-sphere) is ambiguous and too broad, and we need a tag for this concept.
- I agreed with her thought, but I also suggested making it explicit in the tag wiki for [sexual-misconduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-misconduct) that no judgment is implied. We have now edited the wiki.

After pondering on it for a while, I now think that this proposal is the best course of action.

Comment: Note that you can propose a tag synonym [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: @ff524 I just wanted to make sure that the community agrees with it before.

Comment: Are you asking whether the community supports a rename or a tag synonym creation?  I have no objection to the latter, but I'm not the right person to weigh in on that, because I don't have much experience with tag synonyms.  However, I do not support a rename.

Comment: @aparente001 My proposal is that sexual-conduct be the master tag, and sexual-misconduct a tag synonym. This does not trigger a mass rename for past questions, but in most places where the synonym shows up in the UI it is automatically replaced by the master tag. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/243091 for the exact behavior.

Comment: I think the moderator ff-something was on the right track.  And "sexual-misconduct" should be the master tag for the reasons that user explained.  Sorry I'm not providing a link, I forget where I read it.

Comment: @aparente001 in the current situation it would make very little sense to create a tag synonym with "conduct" not the master. It's only use would be to help users find the tag "misconduct." I do not think this is a major concern. // Federico: I do not see what the issue with triggering a mass rename would be. Either "conduct" is a good tag for that type of question or it isn't. If the former then I do not see a problem with it being applied retroactively.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with the tag renaming.

Sexual misconduct is often more about power or the abuse of power than it is about sex.

Rape was once seen as a subset of 'sex' but is now appropriately being seen as the vicious form of abuse and crime that it is.

Answer (score 2):

The term for this concept in English is "sexual misconduct"; this is a [term of art](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Term+of+Art), whose meaning cannot necessarily be broken down to its constituent parts.

Those who have chosen to tag questions with this label assumedly meant to use this term, and not some other term with different connotations. Therefore it would be inappropriate to rename this tag to some other term.

Regarding the proposed alternatives:

- "Sexual sphere" is not a phrase in English.
- As for "sexual conduct", the OP may be relieved to learn that this is a term found largely in legal codes that criminalize certain sexual behaviors such as statutory rape or bestiality. Therefore if his goal is to avoid stigmatizing the hypothetical individuals who are tagged with this label, his proposed term would actually be far worse!

Comment: Generally, tags are there to categorize the content of the site. This categorization is not solely or even primarily to be based on an author's preferences, but is rather to be decided according to the needs and customs of the site. Moreover "[t]hose who have chosen to tag questions with this label assumedly meant to use this term" is a bit tautological and  an oversimplification in that many a user is limited to the existing tags to begin with  (or might feel limited even if not being technically constrained to use them).

Comment: My point was simply that a tag rename shouldn't change the meaning of the tag, even if in one case this seems appropriate, because such a change also affects all the previously-tagged questions. A tag rename from "ring" to "commutative associative unital ring" would be a bad idea, even if the latter is clearer, since all the existing posts about Hopf algebras and matrix rings are now going to be mislabeled.

Comment: By OP's intent the proposed change seems rather the *opposite* rename. It meant to *extend* the scope of the tag. The proposed name might not be good, yet another one might serve the *intended* purpose.

Comment: Apologies, but English is not my first language, so I might have missed a few nuances. Do you have another suggestion for a hypernym of "sexual misconduct" that does not imply a judgment?

Comment: Also, let me stress it once again: there is the option in the SE interface to replace uses of the tag "sexual misconduct" with something else (redirect) for **new** questions only, while leaving the tag as it is on old questions. Actually, it is the default behavior when a tag redirect is created. This should solve one of @TomChurch's concerns.